# Automate publishing of WMS or WFS Layer in GeoServer using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver-rest-api

How to automate publishing of a WMS or WFS Layer in Geoserver given any data source (vector/shape-files/GeoJson...) using OpenLayers 3 script

There is a possibility to automate Geoserver operations using REST API, but I couldn't found how to link it with OpenLayers 3.

Comment: Hi Sarah.  Could you please add a little more detail on your question to help find an answer.  For example, why you need to automate the publishing, and where do you want the layers to be published (e.g. format, for who)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Well, the purpose of automating this operation is to publish a lot of layers (each layer is a result of some applied operations in openlayers).These layers will be published in geonetwork.

Comment: I think you can start here http://geoserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest/examples/curl.html

Comment: Thank you for your help.                                                       
Well, I see this solution, but my problem is that I don't know how to integrate this processus in an Openlayers3 script.